# Programatically create exclusion parameters in Apache CXF?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I'm building a RESTful web service that queries a database using a QueryCriteria object. QueryCriteria has fields like 'color' and 'shape.'

Right now I have an endpoint that binds query params to this query criteria object, e.g.

```
public String getObject(@Context final HttpServletRequest httpRequest_, 
@QueryParam("") final QueryCriteria criteria){
...
}
```

I want to be able to query for color!=Blue. However, the only way I can think of doing this is, for every field in QueryCriteria, having an exclusion field, e.g. excludeColor, excludeShape.

This will add a lot of bloat to my criteria objects, is there a more elegant solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

OK, here is one solution I thought of.

For each field, make two setters, e.g. setExcludeColor and setColor. Both will modify a Pair, where the Left of the pair is what to include and the right is what to exclude.